"coffee making countries" vs. "coffee-making countries"?

The graph illustrates how much coffee was produced in four premier coffee making countries between 2011 and 2013.

Is a hyphen between "coffee" and "making" a must here? I'm talking about the top four coffee producing countries in the world.

Duplicate of a bunch of questions: 1 2 3 4

If what we want to say is top, then instead of saying premier we should just say

The graph illustrates how much coffee was produced in the top four coffee producing countries between 2011 and 2013.

Producing is more appropriate than making if we are talking about farm outputs.
The OP's example without the hyphen

... four premier coffee making countries ...

is likely to be interpreted as talking about countries producing top grade coffee:

.. four premier-coffee making countries ...

Edit
Hence, the hyphen is needed if we want to go for that construction.

Thank you both for your answers. I wonder, though, why it has to be "top" instead of "premier", and is "making" unnatural here? I know "producing" sounds great, but I don't want to repeat it too many times throughout my essay.

Among making, harvesting, yielding, and cultivating, which one(s) is/are okay to replace "producing". I suppose it's "yielding", isn't it?

@anIELTSlearner "Top" has at least two meanings as an adjective. It can mean top quality, or it can mean top quantity. In this case, it means top quantity. "Premier", on the other hand, only means top quality, so it doesn't make sense in this case. "A premier coffee-making country" means a coffee-making country of the highest quality -- that's to say, the country is the highest quality.

Top-quality coffee, "top quality" belong together and modify the noun "coffee" but "expensive-top quality coffee" I wouldn't put "expensive and top" together. Likewise premier-coffee making countries is weird, it sounds like some very good coffee is creating countries. OK, common sense tells us this is not so, but premier coffee-making countries or even “premier-coffeee-making countries” work better.

Yes, the hyphen must be there.
When there's several words which act as a single attributive adjective, then hyphens are required.
"A coffee making country", without the hyphen, is a cup of coffee that is making country music.
That's one strong cup of coffee.

Also see a man eating lion, a hard working man, a red hot iron bar, etc.
